# Loop simultaneously over two lists in R

Tags: r, loops

I have written a function that takes three arguments:

```
create.template <- function(t.list, x, y){
    temp <- cbind(get(t.list[x]), get(t.list[y]), NA)
}
```

The output of this function is a data.frame with 11 columns and 17 rows.

Now I would like to create a loop over the function with two lists, one for x and one for y. Thereby

```
x.list <- list(1,2,3)
y.list <- list(4,5,6)
```

In the final step I would like to establish something like

```
for (x in x.list and y in y.list){
   create.template(t.list, x, y)
}
```

and possibly combine the resulting dataframes (3 dataframes with 11 columns each) rowwise in one final dataframe.

I know that you can do this in Python with the zip() function and then append the results easily by append() and concatenate(), but I have not found an equivalent in R so far. Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `mapply` or `Map`

Comment: What is `cind` in your code.  Is it `cbind`

Answer (score 0):

We can get the values of multiple objects with `mget`, use either `Reduce` or `do.call` to `cbind` the `list` of `vectors`

```
Reduce(cbind, c(mget(ls(pattern = "\\.list")), NA))
```

Or

```
do.call(cbind, c(mget(c("x.list", "y.list")), NA))
```